# compare colums of two table if table1.row > table2.row

Tags: mysql, sql-server, compare

TABLE1

```
mybb_users
(id gcoins)
 1    150
 2    10
```

TABLE2

```
servercoins
(id prezzo)
 1    150
 2    70
```

I should compare this table for control if users have enough "gcoins" for buy "prezzo". If "gcoins" > "prezzo" it's ok but "gcoins" < "prezzo" print an alert with "You don't have enough gocins for this"

Comment: Hello, Giuseppe.  Please provide some code to indicate what you've tried for this query and where it is failing.

Comment: @STLDeveloper I tried this but i think it's impossibile for syntax: SELECT gcoins FROM mybb_users WHERE uid = '$uid' > SELECT prezzo FROM servercoins WHERE id = '$id'

Comment: mysql or sql server? The code may be different depending on the DBMS you are actually using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
SELECT
   CASE WHEN ((SELECT gcoins 
               FROM TABLA1
               WHERE  TABLA1.id = <ID_USER> 
                      AND gcoins >0) < ( SELECT prezzo 
                                          FROM TABLA2
                                          WHERE TABLA2.id = <ID_PREZZO>)) 
        THEN 'You dont have enough gocins for this'
        ELSE 'something else...'
   END
```

`<ID_USER>` and `<ID_PREZZO>` replace with your variables.

[HERE](http://rextester.com/WDNI76918) you can test!

Hope this help!

Comment: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'THEN 'You don't have enough gocins for this' ELSE 'something else...' ' at line 8

Comment: You have tagged this for "SQL Server".  So why are you asking about MySQL?

Comment: What do u mean for "usr" or "svr" ? Error: Unknown column 'usr.id' in 'where clause'

Comment: here you cant test... remember use your id's from users and prezzos..
http://rextester.com/WDNI76918

Comment: if I use this syntax how fix echo and else? if(mysql_query("

SELECT
   CASE WHEN ((SELECT gcoins 
               FROM mybb_users
               WHERE  mybb_users.uid = $uid
                      AND gcoins >0) < ( SELECT prezzo 
                                          FROM servercoins
                                          WHERE servercoins.id = $id))
       
"))
{
    echo ('You dont have enough gocins for this');
      }
    else {('something else...');
    }
  
mysql_close($con);
?>

Comment: if run the query same your code I show only white page

Comment: yes, because my query is generic, you need add your ID to filter and compare. What lenguaje are u using to code? 
Now you got a new question, is not the same, now u are question how to add your id values in the query.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43141370/add-id-values-in-the-compare-select?noredirect=1#comment73361069_43141370

Answer (score 0):

This is a general query that will print out the status:

```
SELECT u.id, u.gcoins, s.prezzo,
       CASE WHEN u.gcoins >= s.prezzo THEN 'OK' else 'Not Enough gcoins' END AS Status
  FROM mybb_users u
       INNER JOIN servercoins s ON u.id = s.id
```

If you want a query that just returns the rows that need the alert, then remove the second line, and add a WHERE clause instead:

```
SELECT u.id, u.gcoins, s.prezzo
  FROM mybb_users u
       INNER JOIN servercoins s ON u.id = s.id
 WHERE u.gcoins < s.prezzo
```

This gives you a list of those who need to be warned that they don't have enough gcoins.

Comment: for "u" and "s" you mean "mybb_users" and "servercoins" really?

Comment: @M56, that's standard JOIN syntax

Comment: @Giuseppe That's standard table aliasing. Alias "mybb_users" as u, "servercoins" as s, and then refer to the u. and s. aliases to save typing and make the code easier to read and less verbose.

Comment: what do u mean for "list", I should this compare when u.$id click this product and if u.$id have enough gcoins he buy this product conversely print alert with Not Enough gcoins

Comment: Run the SQL and find out. It just lists out the results that match what you want. What you do with the results is up to you.

Comment: If you only wanted the info for a SPECIFIC id, you just add an "AND u.id = X" where X is the ID you're interested in.